# Why i am getting "Remove type arguments" error for "List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();"

Tags: java, arraylist

i am trying to implementing **ArrayList** using String array.

while implementing i am getting **Remove type arguments** error in my *eclipse*.

**ArrayList.java**

```
import java.util.List;


public class ArrayList {

public static void main(String [] a)
{
    String [] things = {"eggs","chicken","milk","butter"};
    List<String> list1 =  new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String s: things)
        list1.add(s);

    String [] morethings = {"chicken","milk"};
    List<String> list2 = (List<String>) new ArrayList ();

    for(String y: morethings)
        list2.add(y);
    for(int i=0; i<list1.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s ", list1.get(i));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've defined your own `ArrayList` which is not a generic class. To use `java.util.ArrayList` simply rename your class to something else other than one of Java's built-in classes

Answer (score 2):

You have used the class java.awt.List which is used for GUI List options such as creating a drop-down list, and thus one cannot use collectibles/data structure, Iterators with such a list.
You need to use java.util.List for implementing:
List>= new LinkedList>();